# Allow user to dynamically select the factor to compute statistics in shinyApp

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
dat <- data.frame(Concentration = c("Placebo","Placebo","Placebo","Placebo","Placebo","Placebo","Low","Low","Low","Low","Low","Low", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High"),
                 Value = c(0.0400, 0.04, 0.0200, 0.03, -0.00500, 0.0300, -0.04, 0, -0.1, -0.0200,  -0.0100, -0.0100, 0.0100, -0.0100, -0.05, 0.03,  0.0200, NA, 0.0100, 0.04, -0.0200, -0.00700, 0.0100, NA))
```

There's a function called `cohen.d()` from the `library(effsize)` package, that allows you to calculate the effect size between two groups. You could do, for exmaple, `cohen.d(dat$Low, dat$Medium)` to obtain the effect size between this two columns.

However, I would like to create a shinyApp that allows the user to select two variables, and compute the cohensD between one of the columns and the rest of them based on the user's selection.

So in the previous example, the user would choose for example Placebo, and obtain the cohens D between Placebo vs Low, Placebo vs Medium, etc.

In the following RepEx you can find the app, almost finished.

```
# Shiny
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjqui)
library(shinyjs)

# Data
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(vcd)
library(effsize)
library(RcppAlgos)
library(psych)
library(tidyverse)

not_sel <- "Not Selected"

dat <- data.frame(Concentration = c("Placebo","Placebo","Placebo","Placebo","Placebo","Placebo","Low","Low","Low","Low","Low","Low", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High"),
                 Value = c(0.0400, 0.04, 0.0200, 0.03, -0.00500, 0.0300, -0.04, 0, -0.1, -0.0200,  -0.0100, -0.0100, 0.0100, -0.0100, -0.05, 0.03,  0.0200, NA, 0.0100, 0.04, -0.0200, -0.00700, 0.0100, NA))



ui <- navbarPage(
  tabPanel(
    "",
    fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        sidebarPanel(
          title = "Inputs",
          fileInput("csv_input", "Select CSV file to import", accept = c(".csv")),
          selectInput("num_var_1", "Variable X axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
          selectInput("num_var_2", "Variable Y axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
          uiOutput("binning"),
          br(),
          actionButton("run_button", "Run Analysis", icon = icon("play"))
        ),
        
        # Main panel
        mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel(
              "Plot",
              br(),
              uiOutput("var_stats"),
              br(),
              verbatimTextOutput("cohend"),),
           )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output){
  
  # Load data and update inputs
  data_input <- reactive({
    #req(input$csv_input)
    #inFile <- input$csv_input
    #read.csv(inFile$datapath, 1)
    dat
  })
  
  observeEvent(data_input(),{
    choices <- c(not_sel, names(data_input()))
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_1", choices = choices)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_2", choices = choices)
  })
  
  num_var_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_1)
  num_var_2 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_2)
  
  output$var_stats <- renderUI({
    req(input$num_var_1, data_input())
    if (input$num_var_1 != not_sel) {
      a <- unique(data_input()[[input$num_var_1]])
      pickerInput(inputId = 'selected_factors_stats',
                  label = 'Select factors',
                  choices = c(a), selected=a[3], multiple = F,
                  options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE))
    }
    
  })

  # Cohens D
  dat_cohen <- reactive({
    req(data_input(), input$num_var_1, input$num_var_2, input$selected_factors_stats)
    df <- data_input()
    # Select variables of interest
    df <- df[, c(input$num_var_1, input$num_var_2)]
    #Drop NA
    df <- df %>%
      drop_na(input$num_var_2)
    # Transpose
    df1 <- df %>% 
      group_by_(input$num_var_1) %>% 
      mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
      pivot_wider(names_from = input$num_var_1, values_from = input$num_var_2)
    
    df1 <- df1[-1]
    
    #as.vector(unlist(df1[, input$selected_factors_stats]))
    
    a <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) {
      x1 <- na.omit(cbind(as.vector(unlist(df1[, input$selected_factors_stats])), as.vector(unlist(x))))
      cohen.d(x1[,1], x1[,2])
    })
    
  })
  
  output$cohend <- renderPrint({
    dat_cohen()
  })
  

}

# Connection for the shinyApp
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, there's an error in the `dat_cohen()` function; more specifically here.

```
    a <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) {
      x1 <- na.omit(cbind(as.vector(unlist(df1[, input$selected_factors_stats])), as.vector(unlist(x))))
      cohen.d(x1[,1], x1[,2])
    })
```

When executed, the app says:

**Error: invalid 'row.names' length**
But I can't manage to find  a solution.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need `lapply(df[setdiff(names(df), "input$selected_factors_stats")], function(x) {x1 <- na.omit(cbind(df1[[input$selected_factors_stats]], x));cohen.d(x1[,1], x1[,2])})`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is cleaner if you move the estimation of cohen's D out of the server, like this:

```
est_cohens <- function(df,v1,v2,s) {
  df = df %>%
    select(all_of(c(v1,v2))) %>% 
    drop_na(all_of(v2)) %>%
    group_by(across(v1)) %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from=all_of(v1), values_from = all_of(v2)) %>% 
    select(-id)
  
  lapply(df %>% select(-all_of(s)), function(x) cohen.d(na.omit(x),na.omit(df[[s]])))
  
}
```

Then, in your server function, you can reduce to :

```
dat_cohen <- reactive({
  est_cohens(data_input(),
             input$num_var_1,
             input$num_var_2,
             input$selected_factors_stats
  )
})
```

Comment: Thanks @langtang. Unfortunately I'm getting some errors. As it says, `invalid 'row.names' length` or `incorrect number of dimensions`